# assign javascript string without escaping

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a problem with a javascript string

```
var foo = \"<a href="javascript(foo('a','b'))">test</a>\"
```

This sentence gives me an error

I could have escaped inner " but I am not allowed to change `<a href="javascript(foo('a','b'))">test</a>` this part

Is there any way to handle this condition?

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: The clue is in the "not allowed to change" bit, what reason could there be for that restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either escape the quotes within JavaScript:

```
var foo = "<a href=\"javascript(foo('a','b'))\">test</a>";
var foo = "<a href=\x22javascript(foo('a','b'))\x22>test</a>";
var foo = '<a href="javascript(foo(\'a\',\'b\'))">test</a>';
var foo = '<a href="javascript(foo(\x27a\x27,\x27b\x27))">test</a>';
```

Or escape the quotes within HTML:

```
var foo = '<a href="javascript(foo(&#39;a&#39;,&#39;b&#39;))">test</a>';
```

Answer (score 44):

Several years later, this is now possible with [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

```
let foo = String.raw`<a href="javascript(foo('a','b'))">test</a>`
```

Comment: Only without the `@` it works in my Node v10.15.3 and Chrome 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: So useful when dealing with latex equations with MathJax

Comment: That is very handy, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to escape the string somehow.

```
var foo = "<a href=\"javascript(foo('a','b'))\">test</a>";
```

or

```
var foo = '<a href="javascript(foo(\'a\',\'b\'))">test</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have characters in the string get escaped without escaping them in the string, such as using @-quoted that C# has. for example

```
string myString = @""Good Morning", said Dave's mother";
```

You need to escape the characters in the string in JavaScript using `\` character.

Answer (score 1):

[This forum topic](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/javascript-heredoc-multiline-strings--solution-371143.html) seems to have an 'interesting' alternative, at least. It uses multiline comments inside an anonymous function to enable strings containing both *"* and *'*, as well as multiline strings.

Edit: According to **bucabay** (in the comments below), this method no longer works, at least in Firefox 3.5.

Comment: that is a pretty neat solution. it has no dependencies outside the JS language. embedding it in HTML or XML is externally dependent.

Comment: I just tested this solution in Firefox3.5 and it doesn't work any more. Comments in function bodies are ignored by the Function.prototype.toString() method.

Comment: That's a shame. I was at work when I posted my answer, and so couldn't test it myself. Now I'm back home, I don't need to anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. As the part that you are not allowed to change contains both quotation marks and apostrophes, there is no way to represent it as a string literal in Javascript without changing it.

Perhaps you can put it as a CData literal in an XML island in the page, and let the Javascript read it from there...